# Uncertainty in parameter estimates when fitting distributions

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, uncertainty

I used the `fitdist` function from the "fitdistrplus" package in R to estimate the parameters of my data. Once I get the parameters, I must get the confidence interval, right?

From the same package I found the `bootdist` function but I didn't understand exactly what the interpretation is and how it works and how to get the confidence interval. Especially what does the summary of an object from `bootdist` give me?

I need someone to tell me how to get the confidence interval of my parameter estimation.

Answer (score 1):

`bootdist` uses the [bootstrap method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) to quantify uncertainty in the parameters estimated from the data.

> Especially what does the summary of an object from bootdist give me?

The summary provides the median and 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles of each parameter. If inferior to the whole number of bootstrap iterations, the number of iterations for which the estimation converges is also printed in the summary. [via](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fitdistrplus/docs/bootdist)

Comment: Can i consider the 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles as a confidence interval?

Comment: Did you check the link: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fitdistrplus/docs/bootdist? Please do. Especially the part where the output is discussed. Haeds-up: "CI" stands for "confidence interval"

Comment: @Kostia "On each bootstrap sample the function mledist (or mmedist, qmedist, mgedist according to the component f$method of the object of class "fitdist") is used to estimate bootstrapped values of parameters. When that function fails to converge, NA values are returned. Medians and 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles are computed by removing NA values."  *Ouch!! Bad doggie. The fail to converge samples might tend to actually have more extreme values. By tossing these out, the results could be significantly biased. You need a robust solution process to do the bootstrap properly.*